# Log milliseconds with pytest

Tags: python, logging, pytest

### Goal

Show milliseconds on the logging output of `pytest`.

### Things I tried

pytest documentation pretends to [use `time.strftime`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-log_cli_date_format) compatible strings for logging, so I cannot use the `%f` format for microseconds as with [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

`pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
log_cli = True
log_cli_format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
log_cli_level = DEBUG
#log_cli_date_format = %H:%M:%S:%f
```

`test_this.py`

```py
import logging

def test_me():
  logging.info('something')
```

```
$ python3 -m pytest
==== test session starts ====
[...]

test_this.py::test_me
----- live log call -----
19:18:10 INFO something
PASSED                                                                                                                          [100%]

=== 1 passed in 0.01s ===
```

### What I don't understand

The `pytest` [`log_cli_format` documents](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-log_cli_format)

> Sets a [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging)-compatible string used to format live logging messages.

However, by default the [logging utility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) logs `%(asctime)s` with milliseconds

> Human-readable time when the LogRecord was created. By default this is of the form ‘2003-07-08 16:49:45,896’ (the numbers after the comma are millisecond portion of the time).

### Question

Is there any easy solution to show milliseconds? The way the logging package does by default? Does it have to be hacky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if pytest overwrites the default date format for logging, the extra `%(msecs)d` from the [LogRecords attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) seems to be there for that kind of problem exactly.

`pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
log_cli = True
log_cli_format = %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(message)s
log_cli_level = DEBUG
```

output

```
$ python3 -m pytest
==== test session starts ====
[...]

test_this.py::test_me
----- live log call -----
19:56:57.249 INFO something
PASSED                                                                                                                          [100%]

=== 1 passed in 0.01s ===
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd use `%(msecs)03d`, though. This way, 5 ms instead of 249 ms will be printed as `19:56:57.005`, not `19:56:57.5`.