# How to configure "log_date_format" in pytest.ini to show milliseconds?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to configure "log_date_format" in pytest.ini with milliseconds like:

`log_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`

But pytest doesn't understand "%f" in `log_date_format`. I want to use this date with caplog after and in my case, LogRecords objects I get from calling `caplog.get_records('call')` have date format from `log_date_format` (I use `LogRecord.asctime` attribute).

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log milliseconds with pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782079/log-milliseconds-with-pytest)

Comment: @testfile no, there he edited "log_format" field, but I want to change "log_date_format"

Comment: I see your problem. You might want to raise the problem in the pytest repo. An issue was created here https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5296 . You might want to suggest support of `%f` for the `*_date_format` keys.